# Print without preview - ASP.Net/Silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, printing

I have a asp.net application where I'm trying to load few documents into memory and print it. I learned that I can't use PrintDialog in a web app and the only way is to print using javascript by writing the content into a (hidden) iFrame.

My question is how can Silverlight help me with this? Is it possible to show print dialog and get printer settings and print without a preview by sending the files directly to the printer? How hard it is achieve to using SL?

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't *expect* you to be able to print without preview in this context, as that would be too easy to abuse in a jovial script-kiddie fashion.

Comment: Oops. I dint understand whatever you said. My requirement is 'to print without preview'. I understand that a preview before the print is safe and customary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just watched a video about [printing with Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/printing-api-basics/). It seems quite easy, but I think it has to send the print job as image, so it might be quite slow.